# Button labels in different platforms

Tags: output-formatting, mac-os-x, linux

if someone has Mathematica on a mac or a Linux system, could you please evaluate this code:

```
ButtonLabelStyle[x_] := Style[x, 10]
Button["//ContractBasis" // ButtonLabelStyle, Null, ImageSize -> 85]
```

It simply displays a button. My question is : does the label of the button look good or is hyphenated? On Windows it is good, but it seems that on other platforms it might not be so. For sure it is not good on a mac, I have been told.

This code goes into one of my packages and I would like it to be usable by mac and Linux users too.

I would prefer to keep the button size fixed to 85. Perhaps using a specific font which is available on all platforms. Right now it is using a default font and I am very annoyed that it does not look the same cross-platform.
What would you suggest?

Comment: Hyphenated on a Mac Pro (v. 10.1) for `ImageSize` less than 95, and the changing the text size through `Style` works fine.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork thank you. Using Style[x,9] or Style[x,8] works?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running V10.1 on OS X 10.10.2 (Yosemite).

There may be a problem on OS X. On all versions of OS X prior to Yosemite the system font was Lucida Grande. On Yosemite it is Helvetica Neue. So I tried both.

```
ButtonLabelStyle[x_] := Style[x, 9, FontFamily -> "Helvetica Neue"]
Button["//ContractBasis" // ButtonLabelStyle, Null, ImageSize -> 85]
```

[image: button_hn]

```
ButtonLabelStyle[x_] := Style[x, 9, FontFamily -> "Lucida Grande"]
Button["//ContractBasis" // ButtonLabelStyle, Null, ImageSize -> 85]
```

[image: button_lg]

To get a what might be a system independent font you might try

```
ButtonLabelStyle[x_] := Style[x, 9, "SR"]
Button["//ContractBasis" // ButtonLabelStyle, Null, ImageSize -> 85]
```

where `"SR"` specifies a sans-serif regular font of *Mathematica*'s choice. On my system that seems to produce Helvetica on my system. Doesn't look as good as Helvetica Neue on my system.

[image: button_sr]

Comment: Thank you! How do you know which one is/was the default font? The sans serif MMA font is "SB" or "SR" (you wrote both, probably a typo).

Comment: @magma. I learned the identity of the system fonts from a Google search. And you are right, "SB" was a typo, which I have now corrected. That "SR" is Helvetica is a guess based on long experience with Helvetica.